# vbnet opening Workbook too slow

Tags: vb.net, excel

I have many Excel Files and I want to read cell values from this files via a VB.NET windows application. But I realized that I have a performance bottleneck when I want to open the Excel.Workbook:

```
xlApp.Workbooks.Open(Path)
```

I takes on my Laptop (with 4 GB RAM) about 600ms. And I have to open many Workbooks.
Is there a way to speed up the opening process? Or is there a way to read cell values from an Excel File without opening it?

Comment: If your intention is just to read data, you could aswell read data using oleDb & SQL. that would make quite the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Use Excel as a Database and then the reading should be quick. Alternatively, you can use OpenXml for your operations. A sample is available at: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/670141/Read-and-Write-Microsoft-Excel-with-Open-XML-SDK

Comment: If I want to use excel as a database, do you mean I have to use it with OleDB?

Comment: Yes. You can read more to use Excel as OleDB at connectionstrings.com. A reference link is at http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel/